# Consuming kubernetes configmap in springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, properties-file, configmap

I am new to kubernetes and have a requirement to externalize the properties file of the springboot application using k8s configmap on openshift platform. I have saved the properties file in a git repo as
*"greeter.message=Spring Boot myapplication.properties has been mounted as volume on Kubernetes!"*
and created the configmap using *"oc create configmap myconfig --from-file=myapplication.properties"* command.
I can see the same using *"oc get configmap myconfig -o yaml"* command too as:

```
data:
  myapplication.properties: greeter.message=Spring Boot myapplication.properties has been mounted as volume on Kubernetes!
    on Kubernetes!
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2021-08-24T04:45:27Z
  name: myconfig 
  namespace: mynamespace
  resourceVersion: "53471"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/myconfig
  uid: 73ca674c-8afc-71e1-9a8a-7da609902085
```

Now I am having a springboot rest controller as

```
 @RestController
@Slf4j
public class GreeterController {

    @Value("${greeter.message}")
    private String greeterMessageFormat; 

    @GetMapping("/greet/{user}")
    public String greet(@PathVariable("user") String user) {
        return String.format(greeterMessageFormat);
    }
}
```

Finally, I made changes to the deployment file for creating and mounting volumes as

```
spec:
      containers:
          volumeMounts:
          - name: application-config 
            mountPath: "/etc/config" 
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: application-config
        configMap:
          name: myconfig
```

Now issue arises when I try to start the pod, the springboot application fails to start, showing that it could not find any value for ${greeter.message} in @Value("${greeter.message}") as I do not have any such property inside the application src/main/resources/app.properties and if I provide one then my springboot application picks that property from the src/main/resources/app.properties instead of the configmap.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'greeter.message' in value "${greeter.message}"
```

*It is expected that the value should be taken from the configmap that I created.
Please help me where I am missing anything.*

I have referred this *https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/03/configuring-spring-boot-kubernetes-configmap#cm-as-files* for the same and did the exact.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, you are mounting the file, but how do you expect Spring to find it? You need to pass an environment property `spring.config.location`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   envFrom:                ##Reference all key-value pairs of the sepcial-config ConfigMap. 
   - configMapRef:
       name: myconfig
```

References:

https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/configuration-management-kubernetes-spring-boot/
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/86556.htm

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, Thank you for your reply. The way you suggested works fine but does not require volume creation and mounting. That is just using the configmap values in Env variables. What I was trying to do is to create volume and use that in my springboot application. Can you please help me?

Comment: You may mount the config as a file as well, however, you need to tell spring to read that particular file. You may mount it on the default location or set the property spring.config.location as suggested by @Tomasz in his comment